# Magento 2 Migration Integrity constraint violation Duplicate Key

Tags: magento2

I am learning the Magento 2 platform and I am attempting to transfer the data over using the data migration tool. I have ported the settings already but I run into issues while trying to port over the data. After running the following command:

```
php56 bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.3/config.xml
```

I get the following error:

```
[2016-08-02 20:26:32][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
71% [====================>-------] Remaining Time: 1 sec
```

`[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '249' for key 'PRIMARY'`

This is just too general to figure out what table has the problem and why. Does anyone know which file I can log to get a more detailed version of the sql query that is running to figure out why this is happening and what table it is on?

Comment: Delete your attribute sets named `Default` in `eav_attribute_sets`